# objective-c - re set sender tag after deleting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, sender

Is there a way to re set a sender tag like NSMutableArray does when you deleting an item ? My tag looks like : 1, 2, 3, 4... 20.
When I'm deleting a view I want to retrieve the right order and not 1, 2, 4, 5... if I'm deleting the view number 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. you will have to do it manually. Iterate subviews of parent view from the deleted view's tag.

One more way is: If you are adding those views in a predefined order, you can use the index of subviews array.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted to know :)